# Smart Playlist song count incorrect on music app

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, music.app

I have a smart playlist that has 804 songs.

[image: iTunes Song Count]

The smart playlist also has the same song count when viewing the device via iTunes

[image: Device on iTunes song count]

However, the music app displays 6 less songs.

[image: Music app Song Count]

Why would this be happening? I've deleted and re-created the playlist, but that did not work. I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I edited the playlist to include the criteria "Playlist is Music", and the count is now the same. Got this idea from https://discussions.apple.com/message/22808976#22808976.

It also solved the sorting issue I (and many other people, it seems) was experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The most like answer for that is that not all songs may have been transferd to your device maybe do to unsupported format or maybe you have duplicates in your itunes library.